# ¿Cómo mapear una entidad relación en entityframework?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, linq, entity-framework-6

tengo una consulta y es la siguiente:

Tengo una entidad llamada ***TaRuma*** y lo que deseo es crear una entidad ***Auditoria*** para obtener los campos de usuarioCreacion,fechaCreacion y otros ya que en todas las tablas de base de datos tienen esos mismos campos pero no lo tienen como una tabla aparte, si no cada uno.

Lo que quiero es obtener los campos de la entidad Auditoria para la entidad TaRuma, pero no deseo crear una tabla Auditoria en la base datos, si no trabajar con lo que ya tiene.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entidad TaRuma

```
[Table("TaRuma")]
    public class Ruma
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("Codruma")]
        public int codRuma { get; set; }

        [Column("nomruma")]
        public string nomRuma { get; set; }

        [Column("FlagEstado")]
        public int estado { get; set; }

    }
```

Entidad Auditoria

```
public class Auditoria
    {
        public string UsuarioCreacion { get; set; }
        public string UsuarioModificacion { get; set; }
        public DateTime FechaHoraCreacion { get; set; }
        public DateTime FechaHoraModificacion { get; set; }
    }
```

No sé si es posible realizar ello, pero lo que no quiero es que se cree una tabla en base de datos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrias aplicar herencia en las clase, o sea

```
public class Ruma : Auditoria
{
   //propiedades
}
```

de esta forma la entidad `Ruma` tendra ademas las propiedades de `Auditoria`

Si analizas las estrategias de herencia

[Inheritance Strategy in Entity Framework 6](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/inheritance-strategy-in-code-first.aspx)

veras que hay varios tipos de implementacion segun quieras separar en varias tablas o no

- Table per Hierarchy (TPH)
- Table per Type (TPT)
- Table per Concrete Class (TPC)

En tu caso por lo que comentas estarias aplicando

[Table per Concrete Type (TPC)](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines)

en donde las propiedades heredadas se situan en la tabla de cada entidad hija, o sea si aplicas la clase `Auditoria` a varias entidades cada una tendra sus propias columnas

[[Entity Framework][Code First] Herencia - Tabla por tipo concreto - Table per Concrete Type (TPC)](http://ltuttini.blogspot.com/2013/08/entity-frameworkcode-first-herencia_30.html)

A nivel de clase tendras esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero a nivel de base de datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]